# AWS S3: Deleting all parquet files in multiple S3 subfolders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet

We have very many folder and subfolders in each S3 bucket where parquet files are stored, issue is when data error occurs, we have to manually go in to each folder/subfolder/sub-subfolder etc to delete all the parquet files.

Is there a way either via a) AWS cli or b) using a py-script and running it in a AWS Glue jobs that it could delete all parquet files in multiple sub and sub-sub folders?

Option b) would be great, and ideally a script that runs without having to specify the subfolder. Our folder structure is set, so if script needed paths to all subfolders, we could live with that solution also.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the awscli can be used: `aws s3 rm s3://prefix/2022/09/ --recursive`

Comment: @jarmod Super thanks for this! It worked, it deleted the parquet files, however, it also deleted the actual folder in which the parquet files were stored. Any way to only delete the parquet files and not the folder itself? I ran the following code:

`aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/test-folder/ --recursive --include "*.parquet"`

Comment: There typically are no folders in reality. There are just objects with a common prefix such as `payroll/2022/`. The appearance of a `payroll/2022/` folder is just virtual, inferred from 1+ objects with that prefix. Technically you can create persistent 'folders' (the AWS S3 console allows you to do this, for example) and they are simply zero-sized objects whose key is the complete path e.g. `payroll/2022/`. That said, I suspect the awscli `s3 rm --recursive` would delete those too because they are objects and they match the requested prefix.

Comment: Note: when you upload a new object with a given prefix, the 'folder' for that prefix will magically reappear. It doesn't actually exist, but is virtual.

Comment: @jarmod Many thanks again for explaining. Would use of  `--exclude` in any way help prevent the (virtual) folder deletions?

Comment: No, because the 'folders' almost certainly don't exist. However, you should verify that because it depends on what the client does. Some clients originally developed in a pre-object store era might automatically create 'folders' on the underlying file system. To check to see if the `payroll/2022/` folder actually exists, issue a HeadObject request against the key `payroll/2022/`.

Comment: If you really need the 'folders' then you could potentially enumerate them first, then recursively delete all objects, then create the 'folder' objects in your script.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you again! Also, I think I could add a dummy object/file or txt file in each folder which has extension other than .parquet, so when I go to purge all parquet files, that dummy object will still remain and thus keep the 'folder'......will try out the various methods.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll summarize my comments in an answer.

Comment: If the supplied answer resolved your questions, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can delete all objects under a specific partition/prefix as follows using the awscli:

```
aws s3 rm s3://folder/2022/09/ --recursive
```

The prefix could be YYYY/, YYYY/MM/, YYYY/MM/DD/ etc. as needed.

Note that this will delete all objects below the specific prefix.

You indicated a preference to retain the folder structure while deleting the objects but in the general case this is not possible because there are no actual folders. They're virtual and only appear to be present when objects with a given key prefix exist. If you want to create a given folder structure then you can do that by simply writing additional objects to the relevant key prefixes e.g. `folder/2022/09/dummy.txt` or even a zero-sized object at `folder/2022/09/` to represent the folder.